What are the meanings of the changed file icons in GitHub?
In GitHub's changed-files view, there are several icons depending on the type of change:

Although it's easy enough to intuit their meaning, it would be nice to have a definitive source for that information. There is no hover tool tip or other type of "official" documentation I could find.  I found several sources on the internet which all pointed to this Reddit response, which is basically also an educated guess.

As I stated in the OP, according to this reddit response, the icons' meanings are as follows:
 File was added
 File was modified
 File was removed
 File was moved/renamed
